# How does .axes attribute of the figure object work in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, if you create an empty figure and inspect its `axes` attribute, it comes up as an empty list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
print(fig.axes,type(fig.axes))
```

But the following snippet of code works without throwing any error -

```
fig.axes[0] = plt.axes()
```

[image: Code runs without any error]

If `fig.axes` is a list, then the above line should throw an out of index error, similar to what happens in this following code -

```
a=[]
a[0]=1
```

I saw this code snippet at the following website - https://www.practiceprobs.com/problemsets/matplotlib/beginner/

Can anyone help me explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. When I run the code you posted, I get `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` as would be expected. It's possible you assigned something else to the empty list without realizing?

Comment: I am running the 'fig.axes[0] = plt.axes()' code in Colab notebook and it does not throw any error. I have also added an image of my code run in the question now. I saw the actual code on the website - https://www.practiceprobs.com/problemsets/matplotlib/beginner/.

Comment: Just voted to reopen, as I can also reproduce this now (in both 3.5.1 and 3.3.3).

Comment: Since the question is currently closed, I'll try to answer as a comment: The reason is that `plt.axes()` appends to the `fig.axes` list, so by the time the assignment occurs, `fig.axes` already has 1 element. Note that there's actually no reason to manually assign the axes into `fig.axes[0]`. If you just call `plt.axes()` by itself (instead of `fig.axes[0] = plt.axes()`) and then check `fig.axes` again, you'll see that it's already populated.

Comment: In fact I would strongly advise _not_ to assign back with `fig.axes[0] = plt.axes()`. All it does is introduce the possibility of assigning the wrong index. Just let matplotlib handle it automatically. Save the new axes as another variable, e.g. `ax = plt.axes(); ax.plot(...); ax.set_xlabel(...)` without messing with `fig.axes`.